# Leetcode: Valid parentheses

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, interview-questions, stack

[Leetcode: Valid parentheses](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/)

> Given a string containing just the characters `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `[`
> and `]`, determine if the input string is valid.
>
> For an input string to be valid:
>
> - Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
> - Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
>
> Note that an empty string is considered valid.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> Input: `()`
> Output: true
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> Input: `()[]{}`
> Output: true
>
> #### Example 3:
>
> Input: `(]`
> Output: false
>
> #### Example 4:
>
> Input: `([)]`
> Output: false
>
> #### Example 5:
>
> Input: `{[]}`
> Output: true

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace StackQuestions
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ValidParentheses
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void OpenOpenClosedClosedMixTest()
        {
            string input = "([)]";
            bool result = IsValid(input);
            Assert.IsFalse(result);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void OnePairTest()
        {
            string input = "()";
            bool result = IsValid(input);
            Assert.IsTrue(result);
        }

        public bool IsValid(string s)
        {
            Stack<char> myStack = new Stack<char>();
            foreach (var curr in s)
            {
                if (curr == '(')
                {
                    myStack.Push(curr);
                }
                else if (curr == '[')
                {
                    myStack.Push(curr);
                }
                else if (curr == '{')
                {
                    myStack.Push(curr);
                }
                else if (curr == ')')
                {
                    if (myStack.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var top = myStack.Pop();
                        if (top != '(')
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (curr == ']')
                {
                    if (myStack.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var top = myStack.Pop();
                        if (top != '[')
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (curr == '}')
                {
                    if (myStack.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var top = myStack.Pop();
                        if (top != '{')
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            }
            return myStack.Count == 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Please review coding style as it was a job interview with 30 minutes to code.

Comment: Should `IsValidReview(")("));` be true?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You get the job done in 30 minutes and the use of a stack is the way to go, so that's a good start. In my opinion you're writing a little too much (repetitive) code and it could be a lot easier to read if you use a `switch`-statement instead:

```
public bool IsValidReview(string s)
{
  Stack<char> endings = new Stack<char>();

  foreach (var curr in s)
  {
    switch (curr)
    {
      case '(':
        endings.Push(')');
        break;
      case '[':
        endings.Push(']');
        break;
      case '{':
        endings.Push('}');
        break;
      case ')':
      case ']':
      case '}':
        if (endings.Count == 0 || endings.Pop() != curr)
          return false;
        break;

    }
  }

  return endings.Count == 0;
}
```

Here the corresponding ending parenthesis is pushed to the stack instead of the starting one, which makes it easier to check when the ending shows up.

The name `myStack` doesn't say much, so I have changed it to something more meaningful in the context.

Comment: Cool thanks I was wondering if switch case is the way to go or not

Comment: @Gilad I think a Dictionary would suit well. [Check my answer too](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/212466/35439).

Comment: Since the input only consists of parentheses, the last 3 cases can be replaced by `default`, unless you also want to handle other characters, in which case there should've been a `default` at the end.

Comment: @Henrik Hansen code review just twitted your answer to my question this is why we are getting so many +1s good job!

Comment: @Voile I'd argue against using `default` as a catch-all to cover the last three cases. `default` should be used in a situation where an input doesn't match any expected cases, and I'd prefer them to be kept as distinct cases anyway to make the intent of the code clearer. I do agree that there should be a general `default` for invalid input handling, though.

Comment: This is beautiful code. I don't think I could ever come up with that under the pressure of a job interview.

Comment: @solarflare you do not need to write in this level. My code passed this interview. The goal here is to try and improve ourself. As you can see there is a room for that always.

Comment: I'd go with `default` to catch ending parens, since the strings are paren-only

Answer (score 16):

This is a follow up of @Henrik Hansen. Instead, of a switch I would use a `Dictionary<T, K>`. A Dictionary offers two main advantages: an increase readibility and the suppression of every [magic string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) from your function.

```
public static readonly Dictionary<char, char> brackets = new Dictionary<char, char>
{
    {'(', ')'},
    {'[', ']'},
    {'{', '}'}
};

public static bool IsValidReview(string input)
{
    var endings = new Stack<char>();
    foreach (var current in input)
    {
        if (brackets.ContainsKey(current))
        {
            endings.Push(brackets[current]);
        }
        else if (endings.Count == 0 || endings.Pop() != current)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return endings.Count == 0;
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NsSj2f)

Comment: Just to add, you may also use an array of Tuple instead. `var (opening, closing) = ('(', ')')` should be valid syntax nowadays. This lets you have multiple closings for one opening, or vice versa. It also lets you use C#'s limited destructuring to make it a bit more ergonomic.

Comment: I disagree that using a `Dictionary` offers improved readability. It's a bit difficult to tell what this code is supposed to do, especially if I didn't already know its purpose, whereas @HenrikHansen's answer is very clear and concise. The "magic string suppression" is a fair point, though in this particular case the usage of the magic strings (or, rather, characters) is limited and clear enough that I wouldn't necessarily care if I saw it in production code.

Comment: Sure, the `switch` solution has magic strings, but it's 1. faster/more performant (1 less object) and 2. more readable

Comment: Well actually, technically magic strings are very rare... these are _not_ magic strings. The reason why they are what they are is _very_ clear. Magic _numbers_, on the other hand, are very common

Comment: @aloisdg your solution has a time complexity of `O(n^2)`, the other solution has a time complexity of `O(n)`. You can achieve a better time complexity using a multi-key dictionary

Comment: This doesn't produce correct output. For example when there are other characters than the braces in the string. For example: `"5"` or `"(5)"`. This can be fixed by removing the `brackets.Values.Any()` statement (not sure what it does that `endings.Pop() != current` doesn't do already). [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oJqrYT)

Comment: Oh, I just now see that the input string only contains those brackets. That means there is no need to loop over `brackets.Values` whatsoever.

Answer (score 11):

A couple of small things to add:

- Maybe not applicable to a timed interview, but inline documentation (`///`) on public members is always nice, and would help to explain the otherwise vague `IsValid` method name.
- I'd want to throw an exception if any other character is encountered, since the behaviour is undefined and undocumented. The spec says to assume only `()[]{}` will appear in the string, which means anyone using it incorrectly (by including such characters) should be informed (maybe they assume it handles `<>` as well?). If a customer were to depend upon this (undocumented) behaviour of just ignoring such characters, you'd have another undocumented 'feature' to maintain in future (or else an unhappy customer).
- Any reason the method isn't `static`? Conceptual benefits aside, making it static would make it clear that it's not messing with any state, and makes it easier to use.
- That's a very limited set of test-cases: you don't test for `{}` at all.